# Use headings in letters / vertical space

Tags: spacing, macros, sectioning, letters

I need to use headings in a letter, more precisely in `documentclass` `dinbrief`.

Knowing that LaTeX does not support `section` or `subsection` commands in this document class I use the following workaround:

```
\newcommand{\section}[1]{ { \huge \textbf{#1}} }
\newcommand{\subsection}[1]{ {\Large \textbf{#1}} }
```

The problem is that the vertical space is different if I compare both snippets below. Wherever, using the document class `article` with both methods, LaTeX uses the same space.

Method 1

```
\section{test}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Method 2

```
\section{test}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Is there a better alternative to use headings — and if not, how to achieve the same vertical space?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to reproduce the spacing from, say, the `article` class, you could more or less copy the definitions of the sectioning commands from `article.cls`, which use the LaTeX base macro `\@startsection` internally for typesetting of the title and appropriate spacing.

```
\documentclass{dinbrief}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\newcounter{section}
\newcounter{subsection}[section]
\renewcommand\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\newcommand*\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}}
\newcommand*\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                       {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                       {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                       {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\signature{Mr.\ Happy}

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{Mr.\ Grumpy}
    \opening{Hello,}
    \section{A Section}
    \lipsum[1]
    \subsection{A Subsection}
    \lipsum[2-3]
    \closing{Yours truly,}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I wasn't sure whether you also want section numbering. If not, just leave out the counter definitions or set `secnumdepth` to `0`.

The arguments of `\@startsection` specify

1. the counter to be used for this level
2. the level of sectioning
3. the indentation for the heading
4. the vertical skip above the heading (a negative length means that the first paragraph of the section has no paragraph indentation, which doesn't make a difference in `dinbrief`)
5. the skip after the heading (if positive it's the vertical skip, if negative it's a horizontal skip and there's no linebreak after the heading, e.g. for `\paragraph`-like section levels)
6. and finally, the font used for the heading (here, I used the font sizes from your example, although it looks a bit huge IMO)

Of course, you can fiddle around with the lengths as you please. Also, I'm not sure whether `dinbrief` flushes the bottom of the page, so you might not even require rubber lengths for your spacing.

#### Edit:

You may also have to adjust the lengths in order to compensate for `dinbrief`'s vertical paragraph spacing...

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for your answer and explanation. Concerning the font size: Yes, you'd better use `\Large` and `\large` as in `article.cls`.